# Bypass/Disable BitLocker

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, encryption

I am using a laptop with BitLocker Encryption turn on. However, my keyboard is damaged and I cant enter certain characters which are used as my password.

I have the BitLocker Recovery Key with me generated in a text file. I have enter the BitLocker Recovery Key to unlock the drive, but BitLocker still prompts me for password.

How do I disable BitLocker password prompt?

Comment: **You can't.**  It sounds like it is rejecting the recovery key.  Which means the password is required.  You shouldn't need both to unlock the drive..  Hook up a USB keyboard and verify it will even accept the password

Comment: connect a working USB keyboard to the laptop and type the corrcect values

Comment: What is the point of encryption if it can be bypassed?

Answer (score 1):

Use <del>the [on-screen keyboard](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/type-without-keyboard#type-without-keyboard=windows-7) provided by Windows or</del> a external keyboard to input the password

Comment: The author does not have access to the on-screen keyboard at the boot stage you enter your Bitlocker password at.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the info, removing the on-screen keyboard then.